# How To Release Camera  after use?

Tags: android

How do I release Camera after use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . So how can I release the Camera?

Call [`stopPreview()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#stopPreview%28%29) and then [`release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#release%28%29).